# App thinks class is UITableViewLabel

Tags: ios, unrecognized-selector

I am creating an iOS app that uses a class object, MyObject (interface below):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *address;
```

I create an object of that class called object:

```
@class MyObject;

@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyObject *object;
```

I initialized that object in another class's prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.object = [self.dataController objectInMasterListAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]row]];
    }
}
```

After that, I access a property of that `object` in this code:

```
- (void)configureView {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.object) {
        self.address.text = self.object.address;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this unexpected error:

```
2015-11-05 14:51:00.939 TestApp[26277:2153527] -[UITableViewLabel address]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b6d6300
```

This error is pointing to the line where I access that property.

As you see, `self.object` is obviously not a `UITableViewLabel`, as the error stated.  `address` is definitely an object of class MyObject (I have checked that).

Comment: What does `MyObject` inherit from?  Are you sure it is `NSObject`?  Are you sure you have a `UILabel` property called address?  Post the interface for `MyObject`.

Comment: I edited the question to add the interface, and address is not a `UILabel`.  It is an `NSString`.

Comment: Update your question with the code that sets the `object` property of the detail view controller.

Comment: Sets, you mean initializes?

Comment: Yes, show where you assign a value to the `object` property.

Comment: The assignment of the value is in the MasterViewController in a prepareForSegue (I updated the question with that added)

Comment: Do some debugging and confirm what objects are in that `self.dataController objectInMasterListAtIndex` list.

Comment: I already see the object in the Master view controller when I run the program.  When I click the cell (which triggers the prepareForSegue method) the program immediately breaks.

Comment: I don't know why this is not working.  It should not be referencing a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The problem was that the function that I initialized the object in (called `configureView()`) was not being declared first.  Everything seems to be going OK for now.  Thank you rmaddy and JAL for helping me find this problem.